# Installation of "rlsoda" package on R studio desktop

Tags: r

I have been trying to install the "rlsoda" package but i keep getting an error. I have tried to install it from Github but i keep on getting an error message. How best can i resolve this?

```
remotes::install_github("richfitz/rlsoda")
Downloading GitHub repo richfitz/rlsoda@HEAD
✓  checking for file ‘/tmp/RtmpvtAzsC/remotes2a8794eb666/richfitz-rlsoda-af27c4c/DESCRIPTION’ ...
─  preparing ‘rlsoda’:
✓  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
─  cleaning src
─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
─  building ‘rlsoda_0.0.1.tar.gz’
   
Installing package into ‘/cloud/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package ‘rlsoda’ ...
** using staged installation
** libs
make: *** No rule to make target 'liblsoda/src/cfode.o', needed by 'rlsoda.so'.  Stop.
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rlsoda’
* removing ‘/cloud/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/rlsoda’
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘/tmp/RtmpvtAzsC/file2a83bb76578/rlsoda_0.0.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: I suggest reading the installation instructions outlined in the package`README`: https://github.com/richfitz/rlsoda